# Custom Iterables in Java and Garbage Collection

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Suppose I had a custom iterator:

```
class CustomIterator implements Iterator<CustomObject> {

        @Override
        public Object next() {
              Iterator<Things> readResults = readFromApi();
              return new CustomObject(readResults);
        }

        ...other stuff
}
```

And then I implemented a custom Iterable

```
class CustomIterable implements Iterable<CustomObject> {

        CustomIterator<CustomObject> iterator;

        public CustomIterable(final CustomIterator<CustomObject> cursorIterator) {
                  this.iterator = cursorIterator;
        }

        @Override
        public Iterator<CustomObject> iterator() {
              return iterator;
        }

        ... other stuff.
}
```

And then I used my custom iterable in a Java for each loop, i.e.

```
for(CustomObject obj : customIterable) {
    readObj(obj);
    //Nothing is done in readObj that creates another reference to the object. 
    //The CustomObject is read once and then never used again.
}
```

Will each CustomObject that get's instantiated via the next() method get Garbage Collected once the for each loop goes to the next frame?

Answer (score 0):

So I took a look at the JStat report and it seems like the object does not get Garbage Collected.

Here's my output.

I basically wrote a test

```
public void testThisBehavior() {
    final Iterable<CustomObject> customIterable = createCustomIterable(); //Should iterate over 3 objects

    for(final CustomObject obj : customIterable) {
        System.out.println(obj);
    }
}
```

I then set a breakpoint at the for each loop line and then hooked up JStat to this process and started polling every 10 milliseconds.

I noticed that my eden space went up while my GCT never increased despite going through the iterable.

```
    S0C    S1C    S0U    S1U      EC       EU        OC         OU       MC     MU    CCSC   CCSU   YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT   

    ... This was the usages when I hit my breakpoint.
    20992.0 14336.0  0.0   14317.6 274432.0 212415.4  243712.0   37918.2   71936.0 70562.4 8960.0 8595.9      9    0.069   3      0.150    0.219
    ... This was the first object getting created I believe after I pressed run, the EU went up but GCT never increase.
    20992.0 14336.0  0.0   14317.6 274432.0 217920.9  243712.0   37918.2   71936.0 70562.4 8960.0 8595.9      9    0.069   3      0.150    0.219
    ... This was the second object getting created
    20992.0 14336.0  0.0   14317.6 274432.0 224798.6  243712.0   37918.2   71936.0 70562.4 8960.0 8595.9      9    0.069   3      0.150    0.219

    ... This was the third object getting created I believe
    20992.0 14336.0  0.0   14317.6 274432.0 244026.5  243712.0   37918.2   71936.0 70562.4 8960.0 8595.9      9    0.069   3      0.150    0.219
```

I noticed that throughout this test, the GCT never changed despite polling pretty frequently, so I think the garbage collector was not collecting the object.  I think this makes sense because it has to save the fact that there's no more left once it's reached the end, which means that whatever things were loaded already have been left initialized.

Comment: Although I'm not familiar with JStat: In general, the question of **when** exactly an object is actually garbage collected is hard (nearly impossible) to answer. But one can say for sure that (basically) if there is no longer a reference to a given object (as it is in your case), it is considered to be "eligible for garbage collection", and then it **may** be garbage collected at any time.

Comment: JStat is basically a utility that examines the JVM heap usage.  It has column GCT which shows the garbage collection time. I was taking a look at the heap usage and saw that Eden Usage had increased while GCT did not increase which indicates to me at least that it was not garbage collected. I wasn't sure if a CustomIterable that has finished iterating still references anything that was loaded but it seems like it does. Which means this CustomIterable could be a source of memory leakage.

Comment: And again, I think that the conclusion drawn from that is wrong. You could try out a **crude hack** : `for(int i=0;i<10;i++) { System.gc(); Thread.sleep(1000); }` to ""enforce"" a garbage collection (although it may not necessarily have the expected effect). The point is that modern GCs and JITs with [escape analysis](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/performance-enhancements-7.html#escapeAnalysis) may simply not clean up such a single object because it is *not necessary*. Analyzing GCs is not only a magic, it's a *black* magic...